# gallery view in circular way

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gallery

i want to display the images in the gallery view in circular way , i .e by default the gallery view will show the images till the end of the images , after that it will stop scrolling , but my requirement is that images should keep scrolling from first once the images reach last of it. `<Gallery android:id = "@+id/Gallery02"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></Gallery>` i am not getting how exactly to achieve this.
 thanks in advance

datta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for in an "infinite loop" gallery. I found an example for you that hopefully does what you're asking for.

http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/android-gallery-infinite-loop-56521/

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self plug:

I've made a tutorial for an Infinitely Scrolling Gallery, it's implementation is different to Otra's link. It doesn't use the onFling event and I think it's actually easier to understand.

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/

Can download the project source as well, always a bonus.